# Peer not authenticated in AndroidStudio, but not on commandline-gradle

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

When building my project in AndroidStudio I regularly get the error

```
08:53:33.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

It happens whenever the local gradle cache is invalidated, so around once a day. When I build it from the commandline, either with gradle or ./gradlew, it works and the artifacts are downloaded.

The project uses a private maven repository for downloading dependencies. It was a bit tricky to set up and probably is part of the problem. Authentication works via a client certificate that is specified in a bash variable:

```
GRADLE_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=client_certificate.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

It is exported in my ~/.profile script. When this variable is not set, also the commandline build will fail with a "peer not authenticated" error.

What I tried already with no success:

- Set GRADLE_OPTS in "Compiler/Command-line Options" with -P
- Set GRADLE_OPTS in "Path Variables"
- Import the server certificate to jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security
- Use the latest Java version for compiling

How can the AndroidStudio build be fixed?